# $|\partial (A \cup B)| + |\partial (A \cap B) | \le |\partial A| + | \partial B|$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, graph-connectivity

I'm trying to prove this lemma:

> $\begin{align}
> &\text{Let }A\text{ in }B\text{ be subsets of }V(\Gamma)\text{ for some graph }\Gamma.\\
> &\text{If we define }\partial(A)\text{ to be the set of all edges of graph }\Gamma\\
> &\text{with one end in }A\text{ and one not in }A\text{, then}\\
> &|\partial(A\cup B)|+|\partial(A\cap B)|\le|\partial A|+|\partial B|.
> \end{align}$

It's supposed to be an easy proof, but I don't see it. All I manage to get is that $|\partial(A\cup B)|+|\partial(A\cap B)|\le 2\cdot(|\partial A|+|\partial B|)$.

I also have a hint, but I don't know how to use it.

**Hint:** the difference between the two sides is twice the number of edges joining $\;A\setminus B\;$ to $\;B\setminus A\;$.

This lemma will help me prove the lemma from this question:
[Proving that distinct edge atoms of a graph are vertex-disjoint.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2377803/proving-that-distinct-edge-atoms-of-a-graph-are-vertex-disjoint)
And with that lemma I can prove that every vertex-transitive graph has edge connectivity equal to its valency.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For disjoint subsets $C,D \subseteq V$, let $e(C,D)$ denote the number of edges with one endpoint in $C$ and the other in $D$. Also, for clarity, let $X$ denote $V - (A \cup B)$.

Each edge in $\partial A$ has one endpoint in either $A - B$ or $A \cap B$, and the other endpoint in either $B - A$ or $X$. This gives the following identity: $$|\partial A| = e(A - B, B - A) + e(A - B, X) +  e(A\cap B, B - A) + e(A \cap B, X) .$$

Analogously, we get
$$|\partial B| = e(B - A, A - B) + e(B - A, X) +  e(A\cap B, A - B) +  e(A \cap B, X).$$

Note also that

$$|\partial (A \cup B)| = e(A - B, X) + e(B - A, X) + e (A \cap B, X)$$

and

$$|\partial (A \cap B)| = e (A\cap B, A - B) + e(A \cap B, B - A) + e(A \cap B, X).$$

Now if you can avoid getting lost in this jumble of letters, by adding the first two identities you can verify that

$$|\partial A| + |\partial B| = 2 e(A - B, B - A) + |\partial (A \cup B)| + |\partial (A \cap B)|,$$

which implies the inequality in the title.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just the definition e(C,D) made all the difference and I was able to complete proof on my own. I just didn't know where to start.